# What's the relativistic energy of a moving strained spring as $k\to\infty$

Tags: special-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Suppose a spring with stiffness $k$, is strained by constant forces on each end.

In a frame where the strained spring moves at a constant velocity, what's the total relativistic energy of the moving strained string as $k\to\infty$?

Comment: If this is a homework question, please [see the homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/715/8563). Otherwise, can you provide some physical motivation for your question? Why would you expect the energy to be different if the spring is moving or not?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty no, it isn't homework question, and there's the kinetic energy of the spring for a start. I'm not sure if there's any other energy to add as $k\to\infty$

Comment: The kinetic energy and the elastic potential energy are independent; the total energy is their sum. You might as well take a frame where the spring is at rest.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty sorry, I should have been clearer: I'm looking for a relativistic analysis. I've edited this in.

Comment: Let me try, is the mass of an uncompressed spring less than that of a compressed spring? once you know the mass in rest frame, you just have apply lorentz boost. what do you think happens when atoms form bound states?

Comment: Thought I dont see the point of k-> infinity

Comment: @Prathyush that approaches zero potential energy with a strain still present.

Comment: The point of stackexchange is not to get people to answer someone's question, it's to build up a body of useful answers that everyone can use. I can't understand enough about the motivation for this question to see why it's appropriate for the site, so I'm voting to close it as too localized.

Comment: @BenCrowell it looks to me that the question is asking whether a strained spring with no potential energy still has energy.

Answer (score 0):

The energy is the same no matter what the strain. The stiffness affects the compression of the spring, not the energy. In other words the higher k is the higher the energy density it has in terms of (potential energy)/(strain).

Comment: What about the energy in the stress?